# ActorRefs as parts of messages in Akka (java.io.NotSerializableException)

Tags: scala, akka

Using Akka 1.2 (and 1.3-RC1) I'm still getting the same problem mentioned by Viktor in Nov 2010 in http://groups.google.com/group/akka-dev/browse_thread/thread/fe85adf5aeeec168

i.e., attempts to send a local actor reference to a remote actor leads to the exception below. I was wondering if this is expected for now, or if there is some Akka config setting etc. I'm missing that could enable the voodoo magic needed to automagically serialize actor references as needed?

Thanks,
Is Awesome, Scala

```
[ERROR]   [11/28/11 11:55 AM] [akka:event-driven:dispatcher:global-32] [LocalActorRef] akka.actor.LocalActorRef
java.io.NotSerializableException: akka.actor.LocalActorRef
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1156)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1474)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1392)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1150)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:326)
at akka.serialization.Serializer$Java$class.toBinary(Serializer.scala:60)
at akka.serialization.Serializer$Java$.toBinary(Serializer.scala:55)
at akka.remote.MessageSerializer$.serialize(MessageSerializer.scala:55)
at akka.serialization.RemoteActorSerialization$.createRemoteMessageProtocolBuilder(SerializationProtocol.scala:327)
at akka.remote.netty.RemoteClient.send(NettyRemoteSupport.scala:252)
at akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteClientModule$$anonfun$send$1.apply(NettyRemoteSupport.scala:109)
at akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteClientModule$$anonfun$send$1.apply(NettyRemoteSupport.scala:109)
at akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteClientModule$class.withClientFor(NettyRemoteSupport.scala:134)
at akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteSupport.withClientFor(NettyRemoteSupport.scala:647)
at akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteClientModule$class.send(NettyRemoteSupport.scala:109)
at akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteSupport.send(NettyRemoteSupport.scala:647)
at akka.actor.RemoteActorRef.postMessageToMailbox(ActorRef.scala:1246)
at akka.actor.ScalaActorRef$class.$bang(ActorRef.scala:1410)
at akka.actor.RemoteActorRef.$bang(ActorRef.scala:1219)
```

...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation is golden: http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.3-RC1/scala/serialization.html#id7

I can also add that this will be completely transparent in 2.0